# System is not accepting Password

Tags: 16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04, my problem is that when the correct Password is entered I get the following message:

```
Failed to start session
```

Any other entry returns:

```
Invalid Password
```

I am locked out from the computer, how can I fix this?

Comment: please add more info. Which ubuntu version? which DM?

Comment: Can you login to a [virtual text console](https://superuser.com/a/458507/84807)? Are there any error messages?

Comment: You can [reset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password.) your administrative password